# router navigation: Outlet is not activated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I'm trying to update my app to use the new v3 router than the angular team just announced http://angularjs.blogspot.com.au/2016/06/improvements-coming-for-routing-in.html and I'm having issues navigating between pages in my app, here are my routes

```
{ path: '/list', component: UserListComponent, index: true},
{ path: '/payrates', component: AdjustPayrateComponent },
{ path: '/assign', component: AssignUserComponent },
{ path: '/edit/:userId', component: EditUserComponent },
{
    path: '/documents',
    component: DocumentComponent, 
    children: [
        { path: '/', component: DocumentComponent, index: true },
        { path: '/:id', component: DocumentComponent },
        { path: '/upload', component: DocumentUploadComponent }
    ]
},
```

I want to navigate from the /list page to the /documents/:id page to view documents from a user on the list page.

```
viewDocuments(user: UserList) {
    this.router.navigate(['/documents', { id: user.UserId }], { relativeTo: this.route });
}
```

However I'm getting the error 'Outlet is not activated' and not sure what this means. I'm basing my app off the example at http://plnkr.co/edit/ER0tf8fpGHZiuVWB7Q07?p=preview

If anyone has any example or advice on how to do navigation with the new router anything would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured out the problem, I had a leftover `<router-outlet>` directive inside my list page, and I guess when trying to navigate from that page the router was trying to load into that bad outlet.